# Is there a way to make Octave send automatic emails?

Tags: email, octave

Suppose I leave a program running in Octave, and I would like to know if it stops running, for example. Is there a not-too-sophisticated way to make Octave automatically send an email to me when certain criterion is met?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw, presumably you just want to leave octave running but somehow be able to check the process has finished from home, rather than specifically sending email, right? The easiest thing you can do is to create an empty file in dropbox or something along those lines. As a bonus, you can check when the file was created, and you can dump your outputs on that file for safe keeping too. Just remember to have a try / catch statement to catch errors appropriately (e.g. create a different file pointing out there was an error).

Comment: That's a good idea, Tasos! Anyway I've never done such a thing. I suppose I should use Octave's FTP capabilities (?). Do you have in mind any friendly tutorial to follow for that purpose?

Comment: Depends what you're trying to do exactly. If you have dropbox installed on your computer, there's no need, just create a file (e.g. using `fopen` / `fclose`) in the dropbox folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this but it would be very easy to simply make a system call to an email-sending facility.

Traditionally this is `sendmail`, but you can look around to see if you can find something friendlier. If you're on linux, `sendemail` seems like a nice, friendly alternative.